# solution to rdtsc out of order execution?

Tags: c++, gcc, cpu-architecture, memory-barriers, rdtsc

I am trying to replace clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts) with rdtsc to benchmark code execution time in terms of cpu cycles rather than server time. The execution time of the bench-marking code is critical for the software. I have tried running code on x86_64 3.20GHz ubuntu machine on an isolated core and got following numbers :

***case 1 : clock get time :*** 24 nano seconds

```
void gettime(Timespec &ts) {
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
}
```

***case 2 : rdtsc (without mfence and compiler barrier) :*** 10 ns

```
void rdtsc(uint64_t& tsc) {
        unsigned int lo,hi;
        __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a" (lo), "=d" (hi));
        tsc = ((uint64_t)hi << 32) | lo;
}
```

***case 3 : rdtsc (with mfence and compiler barrier) :*** 30 ns

```
void rdtsc(uint64_t& tsc) {
        unsigned int lo,hi;
        __asm__ __volatile__ ("mfence;rdtsc" : "=a" (lo), "=d" (hi) :: "memory");
        tsc = ((uint64_t)hi << 32) | lo;
}
```

Issue here is I am aware of rdtsc being a non-serializing call and can be reordered by the CPU, an alternative is rdtscp which is a serializing call but instructions after rdtscp call can be reordered before rdtscp call. Using memory barrier is increasing the execution time.

- What is the most optimised and best way to benchmark a latency sensitive code ?
- Is there anyway to optimise the cases I mentioned ?

Comment: You might want to look at how Google Test does its profiling.

Answer (score 5):

You want `lfence;rdtsc` to *start* the clock, and `rdtscp;lfence` to stop the clock, so the barriers are outside the timed interval.

(Or sometimes you want `lfence;rdtsc;lfence` to start the clock, for extra repeatability at the cost of more overhead.)

MFENCE is the wrong instruction for this; it's not guaranteed to serialize the instruction stream (but in practice it does on Skylake with up-to-date microcode, to fix an erratum).  LFENCE serializes the instruction stream without waiting for the store buffer to empty, just for the ROB.  This is always true on Intel, but [on AMD only with Spectre mitigation enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51844886/is-lfence-serializing-on-amd-processors) that makes `lfence` not just a NOP.  (I guess AMD doesn't reorder `movntdqa` loads from WC memory, so `lfence` is meaningless as a memory barrier there, and is *only* useful as an execution barrier against speculative execution, or for RDTSC.)

See also [How to get the CPU cycle count in x86_64 from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772567/get-cpu-cycle-count/51907627#51907627) which has a section about serializing `rdtsc`.  But also, you don't need inline asm for this; use `__rdtsc()` and `_mm_lfence()`.  (But as usual with microbenchmarks, not a bad idea to check the compiler's asm output to make sure it did what you want.)

---

**You can't avoid overhead, it's always going to be significant compared to the cost of a couple instructions.**

Also [clflush to invalidate cache line via C function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51818655/clflush-to-invalidate-cache-line-via-c-function/51830976#51830976) for an example of subtracting the measurement overhead.

But also note that normally it's more useful to put the code under test in a loop, because execution latency before the result is ready is more meaningful than waiting until the instruction(s) actually retire from the ROB.  See [RDTSCP in NASM always returns the same value (timing a single instruction)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54621381/rdtscp-in-nasm-always-returns-the-same-value/54624081#54624081) for an example (in asm) of measuring a single insn for throughput / latency.

Comment: Related: [Difference between rdtscp, rdtsc : memory and cpuid / rdtsc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12631856) mentions that the Linux kernel used to use `mfence` to order execution of `rdtsc` on AMD CPUs, if `rdtscp` wasn't available.  Apparently it did / does order execution as well as memory on AMD.  It doesn't on Intel, except as a side-effect of being [overly strong after a microcode update on Skylake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50494658/are-loads-and-stores-the-only-instructions-that-gets-reordered/50496379#50496379) for ordering NT stores from WC memory.